# netbeans debugger fails to deploy

Tags: jakarta-ee, debugging, netbeans-6.9

I am working on a JavaEE web app with extensive use of hibernate, JSP, spring and struts = very memory extensive. + tomcat 6.0 + NB 6.9

I can delpoy my ap pwithout any issues. I used to be able to deploy the app using netbeans debugger, however, It just wont work anymore !

I have no idea to why this happened so suddenly ! note, my netbeans overall has slowed down considerably ! I have tried deliting var/cache/index -> but netbean populates it back in on restart, and does not help debugging my application. PLeas help / advice

Any hint will be very much appreciated
Kind regards
Alex

-->> debug window

> deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fhome%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext64452.xml&path=/web
>   C:\programming\nb-projects\uc\nbproject\build-impl.xml:969:
>   Deployment error: Deployment timeout
>   has exceeded. See the server log for
>   details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 3
>   minutes 19 seconds)

-->> debug console

> Attaching to tomcat_shared_memory_id
>   User program running
>   Class breakpoint hit for class nl.strohalm.cyclos.dao.ads.AdDAOImpl.
>   Thread http-8080-2 stopped at Class.java.getDeclaredConstructors0.

-->> the bit in java.class, which NB points to when starting debigger

```
// No cached value available; request value from VM
    if (isInterface()) {
        res = new Constructor[0];
    } else {
        res = getDeclaredConstructors0(publicOnly);
    }
    if (useCaches) {
        if (publicOnly) {
            publicConstructors = new SoftReference(res);
        } else {
            declaredConstructors = new SoftReference(res);
        }
    }
    return res;
```

-->> tomcat seems to stop when looking at the DB

-->> last but not least tomcat 6.0 log window in NB

> Mar 17, 2011 9:59:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:139)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBas
>    . . . . . . .

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans likes changing the web.xml file of my project !! changed settings os it doesnt do it anymore, but for some unknown reason it happaned again. So i restored the old web.xml file

AND ++

NETBEANS / OR TOMCAT can not handle my breakpoints in DAOImpl.java files so it seems !!!taken them out and its all good again . .

A dodgy matter it seems